# iOS XCTest Unit testing - setting up a Principal Class

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have a class that is only instanciated once in all of my unit tests.

Note: Stackoverflow code markdown does not work, for some reason?

The question:

1. I have created a class:

   ```
   import XCTest
   class PrincipalTest: NSObject {
     override init() {

     } 
   }
   ```
2. In `Info.plist` I have set: "Principal class": ProjectName.PrincipalClas

How do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I was specifying the wrong bundle, obviously I need to reference the test bundle in the Info.plist file.